# How to get the k8s cluster node names one name on each line on Windows Powershell using jsonpath?

Tags: windows, powershell, kubectl

So using `ConvertFrom-Json` is a no brainer:

```
C:\> (kubectl.exe get nodes -o json | ConvertFrom-Json).items.metadata.name
aks-nodepool1-30294001-vmss000000
aks-nodepool1-30294001-vmss000001
aks-nodepool1-30294001-vmss000003
aks-nodepool2-30294001-vmss000000
aks-nodepool2-30294001-vmss000001
aks-nodepool2-30294001-vmss000002
C:\>
```

There is also the `name` output format, but it prepends the node names with `node/`:

```
C:\> kubectl.exe get nodes -o name
node/aks-nodepool1-30294001-vmss000000
node/aks-nodepool1-30294001-vmss000001
node/aks-nodepool1-30294001-vmss000003
node/aks-nodepool2-30294001-vmss000000
node/aks-nodepool2-30294001-vmss000001
node/aks-nodepool2-30294001-vmss000002
C:\>
```

That is close, but still not it. Maybe there is a way to instruct kubectl not to prefix the names with the resource type? Still one can remove the prefix easily:

```
C:\> (kubectl.exe get nodes -o name) -replace '^node/',''
aks-nodepool1-30294001-vmss000000
aks-nodepool1-30294001-vmss000001
aks-nodepool1-30294001-vmss000003
aks-nodepool2-30294001-vmss000000
aks-nodepool2-30294001-vmss000001
aks-nodepool2-30294001-vmss000002
C:\>
```

However, this question is about `jsonpath`. Right now this is what I get:

```
C:\> kubectl.exe get nodes -l agentpool=nodepool2 -o jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}'
aks-nodepool2-30294001-vmss000000 aks-nodepool2-30294001-vmss000001 aks-nodepool2-30294001-vmss000002
C:\>
```

I need them one on each line. Surely, I can split by space:

```
C:\> (kubectl.exe get nodes -l agentpool=nodepool2 -o jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}') -split '\s+'
aks-nodepool2-30294001-vmss000000
aks-nodepool2-30294001-vmss000001
aks-nodepool2-30294001-vmss000002
C:\>
```

But I wonder if this can be achieved without any external tools using some flags of kubectl or features of jsonpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you even without `jsonpath`

```
kubectl.exe get nodes -l agentpool=nodepool2 -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name --no-headers
```

My examples without label

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name --no-headers
gke-cluster-1-default-pool-82008fd9-8x81
gke-cluster-1-default-pool-82008fd9-qkp7
gke-cluster-1-default-pool-82008fd9-tlc7


$ kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}'
gke-cluster-1-default-pool-82008fd9-8x81 gke-cluster-1-default-pool-82008fd9-qkp7 gke-cluster-1-default-pool-82008fd9-tlc7
```

**EDIT1:**
As was discussed in comments, posting one more answer, this time using `jsonpath`

```
kubectl get nodes -l agentpool=nodepool2 -o "jsonpath={range $.items[*].metadata.name}{}{'\n'}{end}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But I am specifically curious about jsonpath - if that can be used to achieve the same goal.

Comment: try `kubectl get nodes -l agentpool=nodepool2 -o 'jsonpath={range $.items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}'`. it works for me. Ill update answer once you confirm it works for you

Comment: It works on linux. In order to work both on linux and windows I had to switch double and single quotes. But it does work. Please, update your answer. If you could also explain how it works, that would be fantastic.

Comment: I think I understand how it works. A slight variant would be `kubectl get nodes -l agentpool=nodepool2 -o "jsonpath={range $.items[*].metadata.name}{}{'\n'}{end}"`

Comment: glad to hear it works for you. Updated the answer with your version